# performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: unable to change delay value

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have very simple method that is being called by performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: however no matter what value I assign to afterDelay, the method is always fired after a 10 second delay. The method calls a URLRequest that when complete, invokes another request (not sure this has implications or not).

I have:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)connection {
    [self performSelector:@selector(poll) withObject:nil afterDelay: 1];
}
.....
-(void)poll
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    ....
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self] autorelease];
    .....
}
```

No matter what value I assign to afterDelay, the method is *always* invoked after 10 seconds. Any ideas as to what might cause this?

Comment: How are you determining that `poll` doesn't start until 10 seconds after `performSelector:...` is called?

Comment: See below - just answered a similar question. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your NSURLConnectionDelegate getting messages on a thread different from the main thread? If so then post your message to the mainThread instead:

```
NSLog(@"WILL SEND wait1sec");
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(wait1sec) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

then

```
- (void)wait1sec
{
    NSLog(@"GOT wait1sec");
    [self performSelector:@selector(poll) withObject:nil afterDelay: 1];
}
- (void)poll
{
    NSLog(@"GOT poll()");
    ...
```

PS: you can do this more easily with dispatch_after() but you didn't mention blocks so didn't go there.

PS: try adding this to all your delegate messages:

```
-(void....
{
    assert([NSThread isMainThread]);
    ...
```

If that does not crash your app, then something is blocking our main runLoop - the one on your main thread - so you are probably waiting on something somewhere. In this case your UI would be totally unresponsive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the NSURLConnectionDelegate is self, so this has the same result. Any other ideas?

Comment: So your code doesn't work, but you want to tell me this won't work? The point is if the callbacks are not on the main thread your performSector is queued up on the runloop of whatever thread you are on in the callback.

Comment: [NSThread isMainThread] returns true and UI is responsive so I don't think it's being held up by another process and yes, I tried your code with the same results...

Comment: Just so I understand. You see the message "WILL SEND wait1sec" on your console. Ten seconds later you see "GOT wait1sec". Finally, a second later you see "GOT poll()". (you can compute the time by looking at the log messages). Paste the output of your console for these three, then I'll come up with more suggestions.

Comment: I think I may be chasing the wrong issue. Seems as if the afterDelay is working, but the response from the HTTP server is taking a while only on that particular call (to complete the loop). Regardless, thank you for your help and making sure it's on the main thread /run loop is important.